# Spring MVC: Transaction failed to flush

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I'm try to execute a SELECT query on an entity in the Google App Engine, but I get this error:

> Error Exception: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:
>   Transaction failed to flush; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Transaction failed to flush

What does this mean?

```
final Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM SomeEntity p");
list = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to execute the select? If you have spring configured properly this should be no more than `entityManager.find(MyEntity.class)` where `entityManager` is a shared resource using injection

Comment: Can you try using find as I've shown above first? Secondly can you have making the query just `FROM SomeEntity`

Answer (score 0):

The full stack trace should tell you more where to look. It sounds like it could be a database server-side error. Maybe you've run out of space for transaction logs?